# How to handle "-" in grep?

Tags: unix, grep

Its been asked several times but its not clear to me yet.

I have the following text in a file ( data.txt, tab delimeted ):

```
ABC    12
ABC-AS    14
DEF    18
DEF-AS    9
```

Now I want to search for ABC and DEF, but not ABC-AS, DEF-AS as a result.

```
grep -w ABC data.txt
```

Output:

```
grep -w ABC data.txt
ABC
ABC-AS


grep --no-group-separator -w "ABC" data.txt      
ABC
ABC-AS

grep --group-separator="\t" -w "ABC" data.txt
ABC
ABC-AS
```

Comment: If your version of `grep` has Perl regexes available, you can use a negative lookahead.  You can look for `ABC` and then post-filter `grep -v 'ABC-[A-Z]'` or thereabouts.

Comment: With the revised description, can you use `grep '^ABC[[:space:]]'` to find the lines that start with `ABC` and not `ABC-AS`?  Or `grep -E '^(ABC|DEF)[[:space:]]'` if you want `DEF` too.

Comment: Or `grep "ABC\s" data.txt`. For multiple patterns: `grep -e "ABC\s" -e "DEF\s" data.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regex

```
grep -E "(ABC|DEF)[^\-]" data.txt
```

**Details**

`(ABC|DEF)`: Match "ABC" or "DEF"

`[^\-]`: Anything except "-"

**Output**

```
ABC    12
DEF    18
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which select only those matches that exactly match the whole line

```
grep --line-regexp "ABC" data.txt
```

Comment: I am sorry. the file contains other columns. I updated the query to reflect exact situation.

Comment: In this case, try this: 

`grep "ABC[[:blank:]]" .\data.txt`